# Indesign scripting create deeper structures by adding tags

Tags: scripting, tags, structure, adobe-indesign

I first set out to do this with XSLT, then with PHP. Now i'll have to have a go at it with Indesign scripting (javascript probably)

My problem is that i have an indesign file without structure (nothing is tagged, but everything has a paragraph style)

Wat i have to do is 
1) ad tags to paragraphs based on their styles
2) deepen the structure by adding parent-elements to the tags

An example:

This text:

```
Titel 1 (style = title1)
Titel 2 (style = title2)
    some text (style = text1)
    listitem 1 (style = listitem)
    listitem 2 (style = listitem)
```

Has to become (on export to XML)

```
<GR.SEQ level="1">
<TITLE>
    <TI>
        <HT>
            Titel 1
        </HT>
    </TI>
</TITLE>

    <GR.SEQ level="2">
        <TITLE>
            <TI>
               <HT>
                    Titel 2
                </HT>
            </TI>
        </TITLE>
        <P>
            some text
        </P>
        <LIST>
            <ITEM>
                <ITEM.CONT>
                    listitem 1
                 </ITEM.CONT>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <ITEM.CONT>
                    listitem 2
                </ITEM.CONT>
            </ITEM>
        </LIST>
    </GR>
</GR>
```

Any help is appreciated! a code-example that does this would be marvelous but a push in the right direction is also very welcome.

I would be very pleased already when i could change this:

```
Titel 1
```

to this

```
<TITLE>
    <TI>
        <HT>
            Titel 1
        </HT>
    </TI>
</TITLE>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define an XMLExportMap-Object for each Paragraph/Tag like this:

```
<yourDoc>.xmlExportMaps.add(<yourParagraphStyle>, <yourParagraphStyle>.name);
```

(Rather consider that there is no whitespace in your Style-Names)

When you defined all, then you call following method:

```
<yourDoc>.mapStylesToXMLTags();
```

As a result there should be a flat XML-structure in the Root-element then

Then: There are some abilities to use Xpath with InDesign and Javascript, but in my opinion hard to use and very less implemented.

So I appreciate to export the flat XML-Structure and apply an XSL-Stylesheet to get a deepened structure.

Hope that helps